# Add JS page to SilverStripe

Tags: javascript, php, html, silverstripe

I have already made a HTML page named **Phaser.html**, and use Javascript and the game framework Phaser. 
Now i want to show this page in my silverstripe site. But i'm new in this and relly dont know how to do it, i just see php code, but i wanna just put my files in someweree and then linked to the page. 
Another thing, When i add from the CMS, this show me a text editor like word. I should write code in there?.
Im using the simple theme. And i have already a structure of my site.

[This is the phaser.html and the silverstripe page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcv6J.png)

I want to put the page on the left in my Silverstripe site.

Comment: Please add some sample code to make it clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added a image to explain better. All of the Phaser page is Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing your code, this is going to be a shot in the dark, but perhaps try this:

1. Put your javascript code into a file named `phaser.js`.  You said all of the code was javascript so a .html file shouldn't even been needed at all.
2. Copy that file into the `mysite/javascript`
3. Edit `mysite/code/Page.php`
4. Insert `Requirements::js('mysite/javscript/phaser.js');` into the init() function so it looks like this:

   ```
   public function init() {
       parent::init();
       Requirements::javascript("site/javascript/phaser.js");
   }
   ```
5. Refresh the page and the javascript file should be now loaded as it should now be referenced inside the `<head>` tag.

Once you get that working I'd recommend taking the next step of creating your own Phaser_Page class that extends Page and move the `Requirements` call to that page and possibly create a custom template for your new page. How to do all that should be covered in the [SilverStripe Lessons](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/).

Comment: This solves my problem. Anyway i still have to find a better tool than SilverStripe. It is not very flexible.